# SUMPRODUCT combining partial text and dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an excel sheet I am trying to retrieve how many entries of a given name occur within a month.

I have the date with my month stored in N48
My spreadsheet would look like:

```
B            AE
Test         06/04/15
Testing      06/05/15
Test         06/08/05
Name2        06/04/15
Name2        06/02/15
```

So far I have tried and was able to get the number of entries that match my text: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Test*",Assy!$B$4:$B$149))))`

I can get the number of entries that match my date: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Assy!$AE$4:$AE$192)=6),--(YEAR(Assy!$AE$4:$AE$192)=2015))`

But when I try and combine them I receive `#VALUE?` `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Test",Assy!$B$4:$B$149))),--(MONTH(Assy!$AE$4:$AE$192)=6),--(YEAR(Assy!$AE$4:$AE$192)=2015))`

So my formula should return 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *06/08/05* should be *06/08/15* then you can return *3* with,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(B$2:B$999,4)="test")*(MONTH(AE$2:AE$999)=6)*(YEAR(AE$2:AE$999)=2015))
```

For versatility it would be better to put *test* in a cell (e.g. D2) and call it with one of these,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(B$2:B$999, LEN(D2))=D2)*(MONTH(AE$2:AE$999)=6)*(YEAR(AE$2:AE$999)=2015))
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2, B$2:B$999))*(MONTH(AE$2:AE$999)=6)*(YEAR(AE$2:AE$999)=2015))
```

The [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) is case sensitive; the 
[SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) is not.

A more calculation efficient approach is with the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, "*"&D2&"*", AE:AE, ">="&DATE(2015, 6, 1), AE:AE, "<"&DATE(2015, 7, 1))
```

With *01-Jun-2015* in E2, this becomes,

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, "*"&D2&"*", AE:AE, ">="&E2, AE:AE, "<"&EDATE(E2, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you, your COUNTIFS is exactly what I was looking for. Interestingly my test data only returns a count of 2 once I add the first date portion to the count if but my actual data returns the correct results.